# Javascript event loop/message pump for Google Sketchup plugin

Tags: javascript, ruby, sketchup

I'm working on a plugin for Google Sketchup that is written using the Ruby API. Within this API is a [WebDialog class](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/webdialog.html) which one can use to render HTML and move data between the WebDialog and the Ruby side of the plugin code. I'm using this class to build a UI for my plugin.

Data is sent from the WebDialog to the Ruby side asynchronously. Due to subpar documentation I was not initially aware of this and now that I'm a ways into my plugin it's began to create some problems for me. Specifically: when multiple successive calls are made from the WebDialog to the Ruby side, only the last call is executed. So, I clearly need to devise some sort of "bridge" which will prevent calls from the WebDialog to the Ruby side from getting lost -- which is, I think, basically an "event loop" or "message pump" system.

My problem is that I haven't a good idea of how to do this. What I'm hoping is that someone can provide me with some sort of resource that lays out a framework for how such a system should work -- what sort of checks are needed, the sequence in which they're performed, etc. I know this can be a terrifically complex task, but I only need something basic: basically, a way of making Javascript stop when I send a request to Ruby, not proceeding until I get the data I need back, and dealing with any potential errors that may crop up.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a great deal of time with the WebDialog class. I planned to write such a pump, but I found that I could do it differently with more reliable results.

( My WebDialog findings: http://forums.sketchucation.com/viewtopic.php?f=180&t=23445 )

---

### Alternative Method

#### SketchUp > JavaScript

My alternative method was that I didn't try to push data from the WebDialog to Ruby. But instead had Ruby pump the WebDialog because `Webdialog.execute_script` is synchronous.

I send a command to the WebDialog with a query. The Javascript then processes this and put the result into a hidden INPUT element which I then use ´WebDialog.get_element_value` to fetch the content of.

All of this I wrapped up into a wrapper method the will process the return value and convert it into appropriate Ruby objects. http://www.thomthom.net/software/sketchup/tt_lib2/doc/TT/GUI/Window.html#call_script-instance_method

The outline is:

1. Make a call ( .execute_script ) to clear the hidden INPUT element
2. Make the actual call which JS will process and put the return value into the hidden INPUT
3. Use .get_element_value to fetch the hidden INPUT value

All this is synchronous.

---

### Javascript Pump

#### Javascript > SketchUp

If you really need to pump information from JS, then I think you need to do something like this:

- JS: push messages into a message queue
- JS: Send a message to SU that there is messages
- SU: When the callback notifies about new messages, query JS for the next message and continue until there are no more messages. This should work as it'd be similar method as described earlier.

The concept would be to store up your messages and then hand over control to the SketchUp side which can pump it synchronously.

(Untested theory.)

Comment: The JavaScript pump has later been implemented in SKUI: https://github.com/thomthom/SKUI